# Is it possible to make metaclass methods participate in method resolution?

Tags: python, metaclass

Consider this example:

```
class Meta(type):
    def method(*_, **__):
        print('Meta')


class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta


class B(object):
    @classmethod
    def method(*_, **__):
        print('B')


class C(A, B):
    pass


C.method() # prints 'B'
```

Here we have a class `A`, which has method `method`, defined in it's metaclass `Meta`. And we have a class `B`, which is also has a method `method`, but defined as a classmethod.

Class `C`, which inherits from both `A` and `B`, in result has a `method` from class `B`.

But if `A` would have `method` defined as a classmethod, `C` had had inherited `method` from `A`.

I'm want to find a way to make possible `Meta.method` participate in inheritance as if it is a classmethod of a class, that uses this metaclass. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: `C` also has `Meta` as its metaclass, as does any subclass of `A`. Should `C` act like it has its own definition of `method`, like you want `A` to behave?

Answer (score 0):

Methods on the *type* are only looked up if looking up the attribute on the object itself fails; compare this to instance attributes versus class attributes; this is just the same.

If you need a method to participate in the MRO, put it on the class itself. The metaclass can do this:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, body):
        cls = super(Meta, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, body)
        if not hasattr(cls, 'method'):
            @classmethod
            def method(*_, **__):
                print('Meta')
            cls.method = method
        return cls
```

This sticks the method on the newly created class only if there is not already such a method; this allows your class (or any subclasses) to override the meta-class provided method and prevents any subclasses from getting the same where it could be inherited instead.